# lwjgl and slick util text over textured quad

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl, slick, text

So, I load a TrueTypeFont like this:

```
   private TrueTypeFont trueTypeFont;
   try {
        InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("assets/fonts/main.ttf");

        Font awtFont2 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
        awtFont2 = awtFont2.deriveFont(24f); // set font size
        trueTypeFont = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont2, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After that, I draw a textured quad, as one usualyy would and then, draw `trueTypeFont.drawString(this.x, this.y, this.text, Color.white);`
.
What this gives, however is far from text, this is what it does, the black is supposed to be text...

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the black boxes because you have to enable blending in OpenGL:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This because the textures drawn by Slick have transparency.

Comment: K, that causes http://puu.sh/aA554/09203ae10e.png ... the small black thingy I recognize as a part of the sprite sheet, I texturized the quad with... do I need to un-bind the texture somehow?

Comment: Or what should I do?

Comment: Hmm weird. You might have forgotten to enable something / loaded a texture. Check this page, it has everything you need: http://goo.gl/GuD35y

Comment: Got it fixed, part of the fix included this. Approved

Comment: @RandoHinn So what was the fix of the problem where you've got pieces of other texture?